# Posting messages to the main looper during configuration changes

Tags: android, android-framework

If I post a Runnable/send a Message to the main looper before/during a configuration change, is there a chance it can be delivered after `Activity#onDestroy` but before `Activity#onCreate`? And is the behavior consistent across API levels?

Assuming this can't happen, which lifecycle methods am I guaranteed will be called before messages posted to the main looper are delivered? Everything from `Activity#onPause` to `Activity#onResume`?

Edit to extend the question:
What about Fragments which were added before the configuration change? Will they also have their `onCreate()` called before messages are dispatched?

Comment: I believe the looper/handler is guaranteed not to execute before onCreate or after onDestroy, but I can't find the docs to prove it.  If this is the case, then you can add your code that you need run before the looper is executed in the onCreate.

Comment: We have been told that between `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` of the old activity instance (called before `onDestroy()`) and the end of `onCreate()` of the new activity instance, nothing else from the main looper queue will be processed.

Comment: Ah, the docs for `Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` does indeed say that no messages will be dispatched between `Activity#onDestroy` and the new instances `Activity#onCreate`. The question still stands whether there is any such guarantee for other lifecycle callbacks.